# How to send email without SMTP port, Host and enable SSL?

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, ssl

I have the following code which if I send an mail its showing email ending fail how to solve this one?

```
public void Sendemail(string toaddr)
    {
        if (Editor1.Content == null)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Subject or Body of Email Should not be Empty...!');", true);
        }
        else
        {
            string[] arryaddr = toaddr.Split(',');
            MailMessage ms = new MailMessage();
            ms.IsBodyHtml = true;
            //ms.To.Add(new MailAddress("admin@digitalprintonline.co.uk"));
            ms.To.Add(new MailAddress(toaddr));
            string fromaddr = "admin@digitalprintonline.co.uk";
            for (int i = 0; i < arryaddr.Length; i++)
            {
                ms.Bcc.Add(new MailAddress(arryaddr[i].ToString()));
            }
            ms.From = new MailAddress(fromaddr);
            string subject = txtSubject.Text;
            ms.Subject = subject;
            string body = Editor1.Content;
            ms.Body = body;
            ms.Priority = MailPriority.Normal;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();

            smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("admin@digitalprintonline.co.uk", "dpo123");
            try
            {
                smtp.Send(ms);
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "alert('Email Sent Successfully...!');", true);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
    }
```

I have the following email settings

```
smtp from="admin@dpoweddings.co.uk"
network host="217.199.175.121"
port="25"
userName="admin@digitalprintonline.co.uk"
password="*****"
enableSsl="false"
```

Comment: You can't send an email without an email server to send it to, so you need to know the host name of that email server.  Most servers use port 25, and do not use ssl.

Comment: if i put portno it ll go

Comment: Off topic: It would be nicer to use: `using(var ms = new MailMessage())` and `using(var smtp = new SmtpClient())` the used resources will be released automatically when done.

Answer (score 2):

`SMTPClient` uses SMTP (protocol) to send emails. Thus it requires the details about the SMTP Server. Consider the code below

```
        SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient();
        client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username@gmail.com", "password");
        client.Port = 587;
        client.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
        client.EnableSsl = true;
```

In the above code, we have provided the following information to the SMTP client to work properly

- Host: The smtp server details. As you can see, by default you use @gmail.com but here it is specified smtp.gmail.com
- Port: The port to connect to the smtp server
- EnableSsl: If ssl connection is required
- Credentials: The account using whose credentials the mail should be sent.

Your code is missing the Host and Port (which are also required along with Credentials, EnableSsl is false, by default)

To know about details (host, port, Ssl requirement) of SMTP server at digitalprintonline.co.uk, you will have to contact the administrator there. Alternatively, you can use GMail SMTP server details along with your GMail account credentials.

Comment: the SMTP settings that you've specified are place in web.config?

Comment: Then, please post this part of your web.config. As MSDN says (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k1c4h6e2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) This constructor [new SmtpClient()] initializes the Host, Credentials, and Port properties for the new SmtpClient by using the settings in the application or machine configuration files.

Comment: is any exception getting raised. if yes, what is the error message (ex.Message)?

Comment: Are you behind any firewall? may be port 25 is blocked... as your server is accessible and working fine

Comment: also, try adding smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false (before smtp.Credentials = .... line)

Comment: if iremove port den it llsend

Comment: i didn't get the meaning of your last message "if iremove port den it llsend"?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a server on your local machine in order to send a message to a `SmtpClient`. Your email service provider such as `smtp.gmail.com` has the server and your `SmtpClient` communicates with that server.

Comment: if i put gmail it will send mail but if i put diff from mail id it will not send

Comment: without tat gmail.comserver we cant send mail
?

Comment: @user3535705 - This is because `Gmail` is not a mail relay. `Gmail` requires every email sent to be sent by a registred `Gmail` user and using his own address in the `From`. Send requests not conforming to this are ignored.

Comment: You can use `smtp.live.com` or `smtp.mail.yahoo.com` as well. Port numbers are 587 and 465 respectively.

Comment: i have added mail setting see

Comment: Write `smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";` in your code after initializing a new `SmtpClient`.

Comment: i have added mailsetting see

Comment: You need to add `smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";` in your code. before the `try-catch` part